# What AWS instance should i use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a single HTML landing page and I expect around 50,000 to 100,000 visitors per day
(no server side code)
Only HTML and a little bit JavaScript.

So what AWS instance type I should use so my webpage will not crash?? Right now I have the free tier : t2.micro with window server 2016 do I need to upgrade? or this is good enough?

thanks.

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no backend code, then you can do it using just S3 and CloudFront.

Comment: t2.micro with window server 2016 will be ok too?

Comment: You should run a load test against that structure then... I recommend using jmeter to simulate that.

Answer (score 2):

**Using AWS S3 Only**

For static page hosting you can use AWS S3. You need to create a S3 bucket and enable static website hosting. For more details refer [Example Walkthroughs - Hosting Websites on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/hosting-websites-on-s3-examples.html).

**Using AWS S3 & CloudFront**

Since you are expecting more traffic, you can reduce the cost and improve the performance by using AWS CloudFront where it will cache the content at Edge locations of the content delivery network. You can also setup free AWS Certificate Manager issued SSL Certificates if you use CloudFront.